# Extract texts from a single file and writing those texts to multiple files

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I'm trying to achieve the following.

1. Find first '**(**' symbol (always located at the start of a new line) in a text file and make the hostname that follows a variable such as '**(host**' becomes '**host**'.
2. Copy text between first instance of '**=-=-=**' delimiter and second instance of the same delimiter ('**=-=-=**') to a new file whose name is the variable in item 1 such as **host-messages.txt**
3. Copy text between second instance of '**=-=-=**' delimiter and third instance of the same delimiter to a new file whose name is the variable in item 1 such as **host-df.txt**
4. Copy text between third instance of '**=-=-=**' delimiter and subsequent next instance of a '**(**' on the first character of a new line such as the next instance of a '**(hostname**',to a new file whose name is the variable in item such as **host-dfa.txt**
5. Repeat steps 1 through 4 until end of file and no more '**(host**' are found.

Anyway what I'm trying to achieve is extract data such as:

```
(hostname1 : 056603) Â 1    
=-=-=
TEXT
TEXT
TEXT
=-=-=
TEXT2
TEXT2
TEXT2
=-=-=
TEXT3
TEXT3
TEXT3
(hostname2
=-=-=
etc...
```

Newly created files should be hostname1-messages.txt, hostname1-df.txt and hostname1-dfa.txt.

The best I've come up with so far is

```
awk '/=-=-=/{x="F"++i;next}{print > x;}' test.txt
```

but it's not working.

Comment: well, the script i posted should do that so let us know if it doesn't. I just updated it to escape the ( in the sub().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post some sample input and expected output to help us help you but something like this is what you want (untested, obviously):

```
awk '
BEGIN{ sfx[1]="-messages.txt"; sfx[2]="-df.txt"; sfx[3]="-dfa.txt" }
sub(/^\(/,"") { host=$0; nr=0; next }
/=-=-=/ { nr++; next }
{ print > host sfx[nr] }
' file
```

Comment: I've updated my question above with changes to point 4 and sample text.

Comment: Ok so that works now with the exception of the filenames where it's taking everything after the '(' not just the hostname after it. An example of how it looks before: '(hostname : 056603)Â 1'

Comment: @HughB. why didn't make the sample data actually like the real data?

Comment: My bad. Sorry about that. Updated.

Comment: @HughB: simply change `host=$0` to `host=$1`.

Comment: @HughB: If this answer has worked for you, you should consider accepting it by clicking the tick to the left of this answer.